# How to write this raw query using query builder? Is my one correct?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

This is the expected result of raw query

```
$sql = 'SELECT  c.*
FROM catalogs c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s.* FROM stock s WHERE s.date = "'.$dateOption.'") as sb      
on sb.id_product = c.id_product
WHERE c.id_branch = '.Auth::user()->id_branch.';

$list = DB::select($sql);
```

I modified it using query builder, but the result is not correct

```
$lists = DB::table('catalogs')
            ->leftJoin('stock', 's.id_product','=','catalogs.id_product')
            ->where('s.date',$dateOption)
            ->where('catalogs.id_branch',Auth::user()->id_branch)
            ->get();
```

Anyone can tell me how should i write it in query builder?

Comment: Any errors? can you show us both results? and which is the correct result set? thank you

Comment: What is the issue with your query ?

Comment: I just want get to know whether correct or not what i wrote in query builder refer to the raw query.

Answer (score 0):

## Defining Relationships ([more details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships))

The first argument passed to the hasOne method is the name of the related model. Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model:

namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

And then you can get the join like bellow.

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

Comment: OP wants the solution in query builder, not in eloquent

Comment: This is more reusable, what is the purpose of using a framework ? :)

Comment: I understand, but may be OP is not comfortable with eloquent. That's why :P